# How do I set a conditional for a checkbox in an access report

Tags: database, ms-access, syntax

so basically I am making a student database that contains student grades, I have a query that gives me a list of what classes a specific student has taken that are part of their major.
This is what the query returns:
[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0D5L.png)

So what I want to do is create a report that has a section like this where it lists all possible classes they can taken per that major:
[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRHxs.png)
and I want to have a checkbox next to each class and have the box be checked off if they have taken the class, if they have not I want the box to be empty, so I don't necessarily need anything on the report like grades etc. I just want it checked off if they have taken that specific class . How can I go about this, lost on this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although more information may be required to answer your question correctly, I'll give this a shot:

Assuming your the check box in question is called "Check1" and the table in question is called "Table1" and the field is called "Test" and the Report you mentioned is a form called "Report"... AND its only on the table when it has been completed.

Something to the effect of an "On Load" command into the form like:

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("Class_UID", "Table1", "Class_UID = 'INF-202'")) Then
    Forms("Report").Check1.Value = 1
End If
```

Of course, this would need to be added for each unique Class_UID

It's a simplistic way to do it, but far from the only option.